# Problems declaring other entities in the ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser> Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I created a project using the .NET Core react + individual user authentication template.
I am trying to declare other entities inside `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>` class but they somehow don't seem to appear in the database.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
        {
        }

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I also have to prefixate them like this `public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }`, otherwise I get this error `'DbSet<>' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) documentation. In short, you should run migrations like this -

1. install .net cli tools
2. open cmd and "cd" to your .csproj
3. create migration -

   dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
4. update db with this command -

   dotnet ef database update